# Saving a jpeg image the right way in php

Tags: php

So I create this image with a php file that give's me this link:

```
image-crop.php?x=179&y=101&w=104&h=104&img=initial-image.jpeg
```

this image is from a image cropping tool:

https://phppot.com/php/upload-and-crop-image-using-php-and-jquery/

So I want to save this image so I do this:

```
file_put_contents("image-crop.php?x=179&y=101&w=104&h=104&img=initial-image.jpeg", "");
```

this does give me the file, but it is only viewable in my browser
when I want to open with the windows photo's app a get the error:

```
file format not recognized
```

I tried using Curl, but it gave me the same result.

it's seems that the image is not correctly made, but I don't know what I am doing wrong please help.

btw

If I get it working I want to use the image in this:

```
public static function fromPath(string $path): self
{
    return static::fromString(file_get_contents($path));
}

/**
 * Create a new decoder instance from the specified string.
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @return GdDecoder
 */
public static function fromString(string $data): self
{
    if (false === $image = imagecreatefromstring($data)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Could not read image');
    }

    return new static($image);
}
```

EDIT

just checked if you open the .jpeg file with notepad it's empty.

EDIT

[image]

I get url on the bottom of the picure like this:

```
   var img = $("#cropbox").attr('src');
    var src = 'image-crop.php?x='+size.x+'&y='+size.y+'&w='+size.w+'&h='+size.h+'&img='+img;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: 'testb.php',
         data : {img: src},
         success: function (result) {
               $('p').html(result);
         }
     });
    $("#cropped_img").show();
    $("#cropped_img").attr('src','image-crop.php?x='+size.x+'&y='+size.y+'&w='+size.w+'&h='+size.h+'&img='+img);
```

var src is the exacte link to the file, so how do I save this the proper way?

EDIT 
this is image-crop.php

```
  <?php 
  $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
  $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $_GET['w'], $_GET['h'] );

  imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, $_GET['x'], $_GET['y'], $_GET['w'], $_GET['h'], $_GET['w'],$_GET['h']);

  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($dst_r);

  exit;
  ?>
```

Comment: 1. Your URL is not same as file name. It's just commands to crop script to what size to reduce it. 2. `file_put_contents("file_name.jpeg", "");` places empty content to file, so that's why it's empty. 3. Your code is too little to help. Check where this content is stored (in var or dir) and place it instead of empty string

Comment: @Justinas I just edited my post to show how I get the link to the picure and how I show the cropped version

Comment: So your `image-crop.php` performs some actions and does something like `header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); echo $croppedContent;`. So you need to check `image-crop.php` code

Comment: Have oyu tried inspecting the file that you've downloaded? "file format not recognized" does not look like an error message given by PHP itself

Comment: @Justinas so I show know the image.crop.php. How do I go farther.

Comment: @NicoHaase yes I did it was empty

Comment: So, what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked all variables in between?

Comment: @NicoHaase oh sorry I thought you meant if I checked the image itself, but yes the variables are in the file name:  $_GET[x] is the x-axis on the file in case of the example it's 198 $_GET[y] is the y-axis (98). $_GET[W] is width (120) $_GET[h] is height (120)

Comment: _“but yes the variables are in the file name”_ - which they rather should not be in the first place - at least not in a format that is basically 1:1 the original query string. URLs and the file system are two different things - don’t mix them like that.

Comment: @04FS I know I just stole it form the internet as a example.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but I do not care about which meaning which variable has - I've asked whether you have debugged the real content of the variables, not only the ones given in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my problem put the enire path after the url:

http://www.rmpdm.rm/nordin/vendor/robgridley/zebra/src/Zpl/image-crop.php?x=223&y=128&w=95&h=95&img=initial-image.jpeg

this link will probley not work for you, because it's a company network

Comment: Can you explain that further? Where does this contain a full path (of what?) after the URL?